# Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup, of order $p$ (a prime), of a group $G$, of order $< p^2$ . Show that $H\trianglelefteq G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup, of order $p$ (a prime), of a group $G$, of order $< p^2$ . Show that $H\trianglelefteq G$.

---

I know that $|G| = np$ where $n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } n < p$. I thought I should make a homomorphism $\phi:G \to gH$ such that $\phi(a) = a(gH)$.

The kernel of this function $\text{Ker}\phi = \{g \in G |\forall a \in G, gaH = aH \} = \{ g \in G| \forall a^{-1}gaH = H \}$

\begin{align}
\text{Ker}\phi &= \{g \in G |\forall a \in G, gaH = aH \} \\
&= \{ g \in G|\forall a \in G,a^{-1} gaH = H \}\\
&= \{ g \in G| a^{-1}ga \in H\} \\
&= \bigcap_{a \in G} aHa^{-1} \le H
\end{align}

However I am not sure how to procced from here.

---

Here is another solution I have just come up with:

We know that
    $$ |PP^g| =  |PP^g| = \frac{|P||P^g|}{|P \cap P^g|} = \frac{p^2}{|P \cap P^g|} $$
    Since the above fraction has to divide evenly, this must mean that $|P \cap P^g| = p, |P \cap P^g| = 1$ or $|P \cap P^g| = p^2$.

- The second case cannot occur as if $|P \cap P^g| = 1$ then $|PP^g|=p^2$ which is bigger than the order of $G$, which is at most $p^2 -1$.
- We cant have $|P \cap P^g| = p^2$ as the largest $|P \cap P^g|$ can equal is $p$.
- If $|P \cap P^g| = p$ then we have that $P = P^g$ since both $P$ and $P^g$ are both subgroups with order $p$ and the order of the intersection of both these groups is also $p$.

Since $P = P^g$ then $P\trianglelefteq G$.

Answer (score 1):

for an automorphism $f:G\to G$ and $h\in H$ it has to be $f(h)\in H$ since $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ with order $p$ and $o(f(h))|o(h)=p$

Comment: Why is $H$ the only subgroup of $G$ with order $p$ ?

Comment: @lhf Let's say they were $2$ of them. Then their intersection would be $1$. So $|G|\geq p^2$